# UEFI hello world compile error

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, uefi

I am writing my very first program to uefi usig tutorial:
http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-programming/hello.html and I have problem to compile it.

Here is my makefile:

```
ARCH        = $(shell uname -m |sed s,i[3456789]86,ia32,)
OBJ         = helloUEFI.o   
TARGET      = helloUEFI.efi

EFIINC      = /usr/include/efi
EFIINCS     = -I$(EFIINC) -I$(EFIINC)/$(ARCH) -I$(EFIINC)/protocol
LIB         = /usr/lib
EFILIB      = /usr/lib
EFI_CRT_OBJS    = $(EFILIB)/crt0-efi-$(ARCH).o
EFI_LDS     = $(EFILIB)/elf_$(ARCH)_efi.lds

CFALGS      = $(EFIINCS) -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -fshort-wchar -fmno-red-zone -Wall 
ifeq ($(ARCH),x86_64)
    CFLAGS += -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER
endif

LDFLAGS     = -nonstdlib -znocombreloc -T $(EFI_LDS) -shared -Bsymbolic -L $(EFILIB) -L $(LIB)  $(EFI_CRT_OBJS) 

all: $(TARGET)

helloUEFI.so: $(OBJS)
    ld $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@ -lefi -lgnuefi 

%.efi: %.so
objcopy -j .text -j .sdata -j .data -j .dynamic -j .dynsym -j .rel -j .rela -j.reloc --target=efi-app-$(ARCH) $^ $@
```

and my hello world program:

```
#include <efi.h>
#include <efilib.h>

EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI

efi_main (EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* SydstemTable) {
    InitializeLib(ImageHandle, SystemTable);
    Print(L"Hello UEFI!\n");

    return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

error message:

```
ld -nonstdlib -znocombreloc -T /usr/lib/elf_x86_64_efi.lds -shared -Bsymbolic -L /usr/lib -L /usr/lib  /usr/lib/crt0-efi-x86_64.o   -o helloUEFI.so -lefi -lgnuefi 
ld: /usr/lib/crt0-efi-x86_64.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `efi_main' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
ld: final link failed
```

I'd check path to lib and includes, and I add -fPIC to my compile flags and nothing helps.

I would be grateful for some advise what to do

My system info:

Ubuntu 15.10
64-bits

Comment: sorry my mistake in question, missclick I mean I added -fPCI , as you can see in makefile above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CFALGS should be spelled CFLAGS. This one gets me all the time.

Hopefully that helps. I would have posted this in a comment but I don't have the rep.

Comment: It is probably one reason, second it should be -fpic not -fPIC and in LDFLAGS -nostdlib not -nonstdlib. and -mno-red-zone not -fmno-red-zone

Answer (score 0):

ld input does not include hello.o because your target is OBJS, not OBJ.

OBJS         = helloUEFI.o